# A linked list constructor that accepts another list as a parameter?

Tags: java, constructor

I am taking a Java class and my instructor wants us to fill in this method:

```
public LL( LL other )
{

}
```

He gave us no indication as to what it does. Is this a copy constructor like in C++?

Comment: no, it is not. Iterate over the linked list and copy each node. Besides, this platform is not a "Do my homework" place!

Comment: "gave us no indication as to what it does" so you should ask your instructor before asking it here.

Comment: @ogzd "Iterate.. and copy each" is not a copy constructor??

Comment: yup, I just contradicted myself :-)

Comment: Strictly speaking, I would say that it is impossible to know without the requirement or documentation. However, it definitely would make most sense for it to be a copy constructor. Anything else would be kind of counter-intuitive. But you cannot know without the requirement...

Comment: I know it's not a do my HW platform. I've written every other method but this one. If I wanted you to do my HW, I would've uploaded the entire tome by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's probably a copy constructor. You'll know only when the instructor gives you the javadoc of the constructor, which defines its contract.

But in all likelyhood, this constructor should create a new linked list containing the same elements as the linked list passed as argument.

Side note: `LL` is a terrible name for a class. Why not use `LinkedList` instead?

Comment: Thanks. I probably missed that point in recitation. Trust me, if it were up to me, I would have written the code from the ground up. It's confusing to work on his code.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually the standard LinkedList in Java has no such constructor, but there is a constructor that takes any **Collection** and creates a new LinkedList from it.

This constructor is indeed for copying lists.

Ensure that you iterate through the other list and append each element to the new list, then you get a copy of the original one.